# How to update to latest 'public' revision with mercrial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to update to the latest public revision?

I naively tried

```
hg up -r "phase('public')"
```

but that only got me

```
hg: parse error: unknown identifier: phase
```

:-)

Comment: Can you specify at which point this does not work? You only want everything that is not draft/secret?

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski I want to update to the latest public revision. I don't know what is unclear about this question?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is no `phase()` predicate. You got me there, I was sure there was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do:

```
hg up -r 'public()'
```